# Grouped barplot in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I would like to create this barplot with this data from csv:

```
group,tipology,value
banana,A,13
poacee,A,33
sorgho,B,12
triticum,C,1
```

A: red, B:blue, C:green

I followed the link tutorial but I  can't split A, B, C

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_grouped_basicWide.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhoI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post the full dataset that you are trying to create the grouped bar chart for? What do you want the groups to be? What are the categories in each group?